# Accessing Parent Properties in Nested Components

Tags: javascript, ember.js, handlebars.js

In anticipation of Routable Components coming soon, I'm attempting to use Components wherever possible in my Ember 2.0 application. I'm running into a confusing issue where I cannot access the parent component's properties from the template when provided in block form. It may be very well that this isn't possible, but wanted to be sure. Here's an example:

Template:

```
// templates/approvals.hbs
{{#x-secure/schedule/approvals}}

  {{#x-secure/layout/full sectionTitle=sectionTitle sectionDescription=sectionDescription}}
    ...
  {{/x-secure/layout/full}}

{{/x-secure/schedule/approvals}}
```

Component Template:

```
// templates/components/schedule/approvals.hbs
{{yield}}
```

Component:

```
// components/schedule/approvals.js
import Ember from 'ember';

export default Ember.Component.extend({

  /////////////////////////////////////
  // PROPERTIES
  /////////////////////////////////////

  sectionTitle: 'Scheduling: Approvals',
  sectionDescription: 'Lots of magical , fanstastic stuff.'

});
```

The issue I'm having is that I'm unable to access `sectionTitle` and `sectionDescription` from the parent component (`approvals`) and pass it into the `layout/full` component. However, if I remove code from the block of the component and move it to the `templates/components/schedule/approvals.hbs` template, it works as expected. Is it just not possible to access a parent component's properties from the block form of a component?

Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It is not possible indeed. The component's properties are available in the component's template, but not in the template that instantiates the component.

If you need the component to make things available, it should yield them explicitly:

```
// templates/components/schedule/approvals.hbs
{{yield sectionTitle sectionDescription}}
```

And using the component:

```
// templates/approvals.hbs
{{#x-secure/schedule/approvals as |title description|}}

  {{#x-secure/layout/full sectionTitle=title sectionDescription=description}}
    ...
  {{/x-secure/layout/full}}

{{/x-secure/schedule/approvals}}
```

Notice the `as |x y ...|` notation to assign names to yielded values.

Anything may be yielded this way, including `this` (be careful with that though, that breaks encapsulation) and actions.

Comment: That worked beautifully! Unfortunately, I hadn't come across that in the documentation -- it definitely opens up plenty of possibilities. Thanks!

Comment: That would be because it's not in the documentation yet. It was added in v1.10 and announced in the related [release notes](http://emberjs.com/blog/2015/02/07/ember-1-10-0-released.html#toc_block-params), but the guides are awaiting update. I saw an updated version in git, so it should come soon.